# Match repetitive data from file with second column from second file

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed

Hello I have a file with repetitive data as such:

```
ENGLAND
ENGLAND
ENGLAND
JAPAN
JAPAN
JAPAN
JAPAN
AMERICA
AMERICA
AMERICA
```

And a second file with unique data that has two columns(separated by "=" ), with the first column being considered a key:

```
ENGLAND=LONDON
JAPAN=TOKYO
AMERICA=WASHINGTON DC
AUSTRALIA=SYDNEY
IRELAND=DUBLIN
```

I am trying to figure out how I can output the second column of the second file using the first column as a matching key.  The output should be:

```
LONDON
LONDON
LONDON
TOKYO
TOKYO
TOKYO
TOKYO
WASHINGTON DC
WASHINGTON DC
WASHINGTON DC
```

I've tried using the first file as an array in bash and using cat on the second file piped into grep with the array as the search feature.  The output didn't equate to multiple instances of the array.  I think there is a way with awk using arrays, but I haven't been able to figure it out in the last few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -f <(sed 's|\(.*\)=\(.*\)|s/\1/\2/|' file2) file1
```

Output:

```
LONDON
LONDON
LONDON
TOKYO
TOKYO
TOKYO
TOKYO
WASHINGTON DC
WASHINGTON DC
WASHINGTON DC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F= 'NR == FNR{a[$1] = $2; next} {print a[$1]}' file2 file1
LONDON
LONDON
LONDON
TOKYO
TOKYO
TOKYO
TOKYO
WASHINGTON DC
WASHINGTON DC
WASHINGTON DC
```

**How it works:**

```
-F=                          # use = as input field separator
NR == FNR {                  # While processing the 2nd file
  a[$1] = $2                 # store the second field by the first in an array a
  next                       # move to next record
}
{                            # while processing the 1st file
  print a[$1]                # print array value (Capital) from array for key=$1
}
```